# What's the meaning of "$" in Dataset's operators (like select or filter)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am a bit confused about using `$` to reference columns in DataFrame operators like `select` or `filter`.

The following statements work:

```
df.select("app", "renders").show
df.select($"app", $"renders").show
```

But, only the first statement in the following works:

```
df.filter("renders = 265").show // <-- this works
df.filter($"renders" = 265).show // <-- this does not work (!) Why?!
```

However, this again works:

```
df.filter($"renders" > 265).show
```

Basically, what is this `$` in DataFrame's operators and when/how should I use it?

Answer (score 9):

Implicits are a major feature of the Scala language that take a lot of different forms--like `implicit` classes as we will see shortly. They have different purposes, and they all come with varying levels of debate regarding how useful or dangerous they are. Ultimately though, implicits generally come down to simply having the compiler convert one class to another when you bring them into scope.

Why does this matter? Because in Spark there is an `implicit`class called `StringToColumn` that endows a `StringContext` with additional functionality. As you can [see](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits$StringToColumn), `StringToColumn` adds the `$` method to the Scala class `StringContext`. This method produces a `ColumnName`, which extends `Column`.

The end result of all this is that the `$` method allows you to treat the name of a column, represented as a `String`, as if it were the `Column` itself. Implicits, when used wisely, can produce convenient conversions like this to make development easier.

So let's use this to understand what you found:

`df.select("app","renders").show` -- succeeds because `select` takes multiple `String`s

`df.select($"app",$"renders").show` -- succeeds because `select` takes multiple `Columns`s that result after the `implicit` conversions are applied

`df.filter("renders = 265").show` -- succeeds because Spark supports SQL-like filters

`df.filter($"renders" = 265).show` -- fails because `$"renders"` is of type `Column` after `implicit` conversion, and `Column`s use the custom `===` [operator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column) for equality (unlike the case in SQL).

`df.filter($"renders" > 265).show` -- succeeds because you're using a `Column` after `implicit` conversion and `>` is a [function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column) on `Column`.

Answer (score 4):

`$` is a way to convert a string to the column with that name.
Both options of select work originally because select can receive either a column or a string. 
When you do the filter `$"renders" = 265` is an attempt at assigning a number to the column. `>` on the other hand is a comparison method. You should be using `===` instead of `=`.